# PHP read response Json

Tags: php

Trying to read this JSON to get value (for example of email or id), but have an error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ../get_test.php on line 50

```
array(2) { 
    ["message"]=> string(31) "Request successfully processed." 
    ["response"]=> array(1) { 
        [954129]=> array(32) { 
            ["id"]=> string(6) "954129" 
            ["email"]=> string(31) "somemail@gmail.com" 
            ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224345" 
            ["type"]=> string(6) "client" 
            ["status"]=> string(3) "New" 
            ["sub_status"]=> string(11) "Unprocessed" 
            ["active"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["accounts"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> array(8) { 
                    ["id"]=> string(7) "2323232" 
                    ["type"]=> string(4) "live" 
                    ["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
                    ["is_default"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["leverage"]=> string(2) "10" 
                    ["base_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                    ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224478" 
                    ["group"]=> string(9) "TSTF24USD" 
                } 
                [1]=> array(8) { 
                    ["id"]=> string(7) "9131428" 
                    ["type"]=> string(4) "live" 
                    ["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
                    ["is_default"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    ["leverage"]=> string(1) "1" 
                    ["base_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                    ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224722310" 
                    ["group"]=> string(9) "TSTF24USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["name"]=> array(3) { 
                ["first_name"]=> string(6) "Jason" 
                ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Test " 
                ["salutation"]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["telephone"]=> array(3) { 
                ["country_code"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["area_code"]=> string(1) "0" 
                ["number"]=> string(13) "6556646446554" 
            } 
            ["source"]=> array(8) { 
                ["source"]=> string(7) "default" 
                ["btag"]=> NULL 
                ["medium"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_source"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_medium"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_campaign"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_term"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_content"]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["topic"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["promo_code"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["address"]=> string(13) "UnitedStates " 
            ["city"]=> string(8) "New York" 
            ["state"]=> string(1) "5" 
            ["zip"]=> string(7) "4546545" 
            ["country"]=> string(2) "HR" 
            ["language"]=> string(2) "en" 
            ["telephone_2"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["telephone_3"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["client_id_code"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["client_id_code_type"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["email_2"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["gender"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["dob"]=> int(477367200) 
            ["created_ip"]=> string(7) "0.0.0.0" 
            ["last_session"]=> string(10) "1522227864345
            ["last_session_ip"]=> string(7) "0.0.0.0" 
            ["folder"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["compliance"]=> array(2) { 
                ["status"]=> string(8) "accepted" 
                ["files"]=> array(0) { } 
            } 
            ["owner"]=> array(4) { 
                ["username"]=> NULL 
                ["email"]=> NULL 
                ["extention"]=> NULL 
                ["team"]=> NULL 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

PHP code:

```
$result_step1 = curl_exec($ch);

$result_step1_decoded = json_decode($result_step1, true);

var_dump($result_step1_decoded);
echo '<br>';

print $result_step1_decoded->{'status'};
```

Comment: "_Trying to read this Json_" Same here. Can you clean that up a little?

Comment: `echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result_step1_decoded);
echo '</pre>';`
should help

Comment: You've passed `true` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.json-decode.php). Are you aware of what that does?

Comment: At a guess, you'd at least want `echo $result_step1_decoded['response'][954129]['status'];` but it's not clear exactly which _status_ value you want

Comment: I need to get concrete values. For example: if($result_step1_decoded['response']['email'] == 'abc@gmail.com')
{
     echo 'Hello';
}

Comment: There is no `$result_step1_decoded['response']['email']`, that would be `$result_step1_decoded['response'][954129]['email']`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Next time, please pay more attention to the text layout of your question (meaningful newlines: not too much, not too little).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us format the output first, to understand its structure

```
array(2) { 
    ["message"]=> string(31) "Request successfully processed." 
    ["response"]=> array(1) { 
        [954129]=> array(32) { 
            ["id"]=> string(6) "954129" 
            ["email"]=> string(31) "somemail@gmail.com" 
            ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224345" 
            ["type"]=> string(6) "client" 
            ["status"]=> string(3) "New" 
            ["sub_status"]=> string(11) "Unprocessed" 
            ["active"]=> string(1) "1" 
            ["accounts"]=> array(2) { 
                [0]=> array(8) { 
                    ["id"]=> string(7) "2323232" 
                    ["type"]=> string(4) "live" 
                    ["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
                    ["is_default"]=> string(1) "0" 
                    ["leverage"]=> string(2) "10" 
                    ["base_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                    ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224478" 
                    ["group"]=> string(9) "TSTF24USD" 
                } 
                [1]=> array(8) { 
                ["id"]=> string(7) "9131428" 
                ["type"]=> string(4) "live" 
                ["status"]=> string(6) "active" 
                ["is_default"]=> string(1) "1" 
                ["leverage"]=> string(1) "1" 
                ["base_currency"]=> string(3) "USD" 
                ["created_on"]=> string(10) "1522224722310" 
                ["group"]=> string(9) "TSTF24USD" 
                } 
            } 
            ["name"]=> array(3) { 
            ["first_name"]=> string(6) "Jason" 
            ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Test " 
            ["salutation"]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["telephone"]=> array(3) { 
            ["country_code"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["area_code"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["number"]=> string(13) "6556646446554" 
            } 
            ["source"]=> array(8) { 
                ["source"]=> string(7) "default" 
                ["btag"]=> NULL 
                ["medium"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_source"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_medium"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_campaign"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_term"]=> string(0) "" 
                ["utm_content"]=> string(0) "" 
            } 
            ["topic"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["promo_code"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["address"]=> string(13) "UnitedStates " 
            ["city"]=> string(8) "New York" 
            ["state"]=> string(1) "5" 
            ["zip"]=> string(7) "4546545" 
            ["country"]=> string(2) "HR" 
            ["language"]=> string(2) "en" 
            ["telephone_2"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["telephone_3"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["client_id_code"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["client_id_code_type"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["email_2"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["gender"]=> string(0) "" 
            ["dob"]=> int(477367200) 
            ["created_ip"]=> string(7) "0.0.0.0" 
            ["last_session"]=> string(10) "1522227864345" 
            ["last_session_ip"]=> string(7) "0.0.0.0" 
            ["folder"]=> string(1) "0" 
            ["compliance"]=> array(2) { 
                ["status"]=> string(8) "accepted" 
                ["files"]=> array(0) { } 
            } 
            ["owner"]=> array(4) { 
                ["username"]=> NULL 
                ["email"]=> NULL 
                ["extention"]=> NULL 
                ["team"]=> NULL 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

In PHP, `->` is used to access object properties. The second parameter in `json_decode()` is set to `true`, meaning `json_decode()` returns an associative array, not an object. An element of the associative array can be accessed like this:

```
$result_step1_decoded['response'][954129]['id'];
$result_step1_decoded['response'][954129]['email'];
```

Alternatively, the following code avoids to hard code the `954129` value, which probably changes over time.

```
$first_response = array_shift($result_step1_decoded['response']);
print $first_response['id'];
print $first_response['email'];
```

Comment: I know OP's data dump is a little hard to read but the top-level array only has two elements, `message` and `response`

Comment: I have tried this  $result_step1_decoded['status']; but get an error Notice: Undefined index: status in ../get_test.php on line 53

Comment: $result_step1_decoded['response']['status']; this not working too. Notice: Undefined index: status in ../get_test.php on line 53

Comment: Ok, but for exmaple I don't know the id number. It will be different.
 $result_step1_decoded['response'][954129]['status'];
How to read every response.